# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx<\infty$. Can we conclude that $\sum_\mathbb{Z}|f(k)|<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx<\infty.$$
Can we conclude that
$$\sum_\mathbb{Z}|f(k)|<\infty?$$

Note: Continuity is necessary otherwise $f=\chi_\mathbb{Z}$ would give counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; having finite integral does not impose what $f$ has to behave like on the integers (a set of measure zero). To give a smooth counterexample, we just want to "smooth out" your $\chi_{\mathbb{Z}}$ example. Let $\phi$ be a smooth bump function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support in $(-1/2, 1/2)$, with $\phi(0) = 1$, and with $\int_{-1}^1 \phi(x)\, dx = 1$. Define $\phi_n(x) = \phi(n^2(x - n))$. These are narrow versions of $\phi$. They are supporte in the interval $(n - 1/2n^2, n + 1/2n^2)$. Then set
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \phi_n(x).
$$
Note that for each $x$, the sum is actually finite since the supports of $\phi_n$ are all disjoint.
Then $f(n) = 1$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so certainly the sum over the integers isn't finite. However we can compute that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_n(x) \, dx = n^{-2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y) dy = n^{-2}
$$
and thus
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_n(x)\, dx = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty.
$$
To get your desired conclusion from the hypotheses, we'd have to suppose some monotonicity on $|f(x)|$, I believe.

Comment: I guess if we assume that $f\in C_0,$ space of continuous function vanishing at $\infty,$ the conclusion will hold true.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath Not true. You can modify the above example to construct a smooth $f$ consisting of a sum of smooth bump functions, where the bump function centered at $x=n$ (where $n$ runs over all nonzero integers) has height $1/|n|$ and area $1/n^2$ and is supported on $[n-1/2, n+1/2]$, and so $\sum f(n) = \sum 1/|n| = \infty$ but $\int f(x)\ dx = \sum 1/n^2 < \infty$.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath it's as Bungo says. The takeaway is that merely enforcing that $f$ has a finite integral is a very very "light" restriction. It's honestly in some ways better to think of "hand drawn" examples to get some intuition, rather than worrying about the formal description in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t(x) = \max(0,1-|x|)$. Then $\int t = 1$ and $t(0) = 1$.
Then let $\phi(t) = \sum_n t(n^2(x-n))$. Then $\int \phi = \sum_n {1 \over n^2}$
but $\phi(n) = 1$ for all $n$, so $\sum_n \phi(n) = \infty$.

Note, with $\eta(t) = \sum_n {1 \over n}t(n(x-n))$ we have $\int \eta = \sum_n {1 \over n^2}$ and $\eta(n) = {1 \over n}$ so
$\sum_n \eta(n) = \infty$ and $\eta \in C_0$.

Comment: I guess if we assume that $f\in C_0,$ space of continuous function vanishing at $\infty$ the conclusion will hold true.

Comment: No, see the counterexample above.

Comment: Sure it is, $\eta(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes you right. I was thinking about the other counterexample. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I went through Cauchy-Maclaurin integral test which says that if $f$ is monotone decreasing and positive then $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ and $\sum_1^\infty f(n)$ converge or diverge together. That led me to ask that if in my question, I assume that $f$ is positive, will that make the above result positive?

Comment: That is, if $f$ is continuous and non-zero then can we say that $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx<\infty\implies \sum_\mathbb{Z}|f(n)|<\infty ?$$

Comment: The above are not monotone  so I am not sure what the relevance is there. Clearly you can add a positive integrable function to the above to make it strictly positive but the same conclusion holds.

Comment: The issue is that the summation only focuses on the value at specific points whereas the integral doesn't care about values at single points.

Comment: I may make no sense but I am raising this question because of two facts:  (1) In ur counterexample, zero set of $\eta$ is very much big and we can't modify that function to be positive (non-zero) and still works good as a counter example. (2) It would be nice to study if we replace monotone decreasing by continuity and proof a one-sided implication related to Cauchy-Maclaurin.

Comment: If you have a specific question about my answer please let me know and I will endeavour to answer it. I have already indicated how to modify $\eta$ (just add $x \mapsto e^{-|x|}$). I don't know what you are asking about Cauchy-Maclaurin but it sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: Thanks. That answer my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

In measure theoretic point of view, consider measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and consider a $\mu$-measurable function $f$.

Now consider,
$$
\int f d\mu
$$
In your case you take first $\mu=\lambda$, Lebesgue measure and then in your second case you take $\mu$ as a counting measure, say $\mu'$. But your $\Omega$ is same in both cases.

Now consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ then $\lambda(\Omega)<\infty$ but $\mu'(\Omega)=\infty$. that become problematic, to conclude about summability.